# Slider with stars for submitting the feedback in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I want to create a slider with stars to rate the overall experience of the app similar to iTunes. Any idea how to make that??

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the weel. Try this: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ratestars

Comment: @H2CO3 is a good start for my comment on your question :) just tap the mark in the left side of his answer.

Comment: But for this I have tap. 
I want some thing like iTunes provide..
Any idea on that??

Comment: You can easily modify this by subclassing and overriding some of the touchesMoved: etc. methods.

Answer (score 0):

Create a normal slider from 0 stars to the maximum number of stars.
Create also an imageview.
When the slider changes value load the value and assign to image view the image corresponding to that rating.

just an idea..